# Getting issue "Class 'App/Category' not found" it

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In Category.php

```
namespace App;

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

and in Controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;

use App\Setting;

use App\Post;

use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\all;
```

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

First   Change from `use App\Category;` to `use Category`, to `use \Category`, to use `App\Models\Category`.

Second composer dump-autoload.

Answer (score 0):

Include it in your class dependencies:

```
use App\Category;
```

Comment: i have already used this..use App\Models\Category;, so it will be showed "Cannot use App\Category as Category because the name is already in use", I had done ealrier

Comment: Please show your file structure because it has definately something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two namespace in Category.php

```
namespace App; //REMOVE THIS If model file is in app\Models folder
namespace App\Models; // Remove this if model file is in app(root) folder
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Category extends Model {......}
```

Comment: now it's showing "Class 'App\Models\Category' not found"

Comment: in Controller.php...namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Setting;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Post;
use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\all;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: in category.php...............namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Comment: I have deleted one namespace from Category.php and only have namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Comment: Okay good now tell me where does that file exist ? which folder ? it had to be directly under app folder

Comment: Now in your controller use it like this `use App\Category;`

Comment: I  am using use App\Category; in Controller now it;'s showing Class 'App/Category' not found"

Comment: run these `composer dumpa ` , `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan config:clear`, Then try

Comment: i tried this still showing the same...showing Class 'App/Category' not found"

Comment: Still has same issue,what I have to do in this,

Comment: As I am making category dynamic on home page and in web.php
Route::get('/', [
    'uses'=>'FrontendController@welcome',
    'as'=>'welcome'
]);
route::get('/post/{slug}',
    [
        'uses'=>'FrontendControler@singlePost',
        'as'=>'post.single'
    ]);

route::get('/category/{id}',[
    'uses'=>'FrontendController@category',
    'as'=>'category.single'
]);
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['prefix'=> 'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'],function() {
    Route::get('/home', [
        'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
        'as' =>'home'
    ]);

Comment: using 5.7.27 version